# How to making GraphAPI Login Session Survive across web sessions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to retain the login across browser session?

i.e. after user has been authenticated through Azure AD for the GraphAPI app and then close the browser, when she start the browser again and access the same GraphAPI app, the user won't be asked to login again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backend daemon that can continually refresh the access_token before it expires and then cache it, that's possible with the user authentication OAuth2 flow.

In fact I've been working round the limitations with the confidential client OAuth2 flow (specically the lack of calendar access to Unified Groups) by doing exactly this server side.  I use a scripted PhantomJS headless web browser on the server to log in as the required user, get an authorization token, gamble the authorization token up to an access token, cache the response and then continually refresh the access token using a long lived daemon process.  Other back end code on my server can then pick up the cached access token and act as the user (ie generate calendar events in the Unified Groups), days or weeks later.

Obviously I'd prefer to use confidential client OAuth2 flow rather than this hack, but until that flow lets me access group calendars, this does work.